Export data with looker studio
I have embedded Looker Studio as a dashboard for a report, but I'm unable to export the data by right-clicking on the chart or by selecting 'Export' from the 'More options' menu.
I am using an Azure database.
While I can export data successfully from the official Looker Studio page, I cannot do so when the dashboard is embedded using an iframe.
I expect to be able to export the data from the embedded iframe without needing to log into any Gmail account.

Update:
I found that exporting to Google Sheets works well. however, my goal is to export directly to Excel.
Already set sandbox="allowfullscreen sandbox="allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" and can export data if i use the iframe src url directly.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I think you need to add more information about how and where you are imbedding the report so that we can help you. If its working in looker studio it will be how you have embedded it that will be the issue.  It may be to do with the size of you export if you have a large file 750k rows, looker will limit your export and miss data, if its over 5000 rows  your intranet may prevent the download, its lower than that its probably a setting on your intranet

Add this to your iframe sanbox allow-downloads
